# Archive all past calendar items in Org-mode?

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

I'm becoming addicted to Org-mode, particularly the way that calendar items (aka timestamped items) and TODOs are both equal-class citizens in a project tree.  As time goes on, many of those calendar items slip into the past.

I'd love a single keybind that would automatically archive any timestamped/calendar item (n.b.: not a scheduled item or a deadlined item, and preferably only things *without* TODO types) that has already happened.

Is there something like this already available in Org-mode?  Can anybody point me in the direction of how to write something like `org-archive-past-items-in-buffer`?  (My elisp skills are weak.)  Thanks!

(EDIT: I should note that I mean archive in the sense of archive files <kbd>C-c $</kbd>, not archive in the sense of archive tags/siblings <kbd>C-c C-x a</kbd> or <kbd>C-c C-x A</kbd>.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would create a new agenda custom entry like this:

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
  '(("P" ((tags "TIMESTAMP<=\"<now>\"")))))
```

Then <kbd>C-c a P % . RET $</kbd> will archive all items in the resulting agenda view (assuming <kbd>C-c a</kbd> is bound to `org-agenda'.)

Related and complementary, <kbd>C-c / b RET</kbd> will create a sparse tree with scheduled and deadline items before today (or a date you interactively enter.)  You can then navigate the buffer with <kbd>C-c C-n</kbd> (or just <kbd>n</kbd> at the beginning of the line if `org-use-speed-commands' is non-nil) and archive the entries.